# How to join the same table multiple times with 3 other tables?

Tags: mysql, join

I have 4 tables 'match', 'location', 'team' and 'round'. Which have the following structure:

> *match*: location_id, team_one, team_two, round_id
>
> *location*: location_id, location_name, referee_name
>
> *team*: team_id, team_name
>
> *round*: round_id, round_name

What I'm trying to do is get an overview of every match on all locations in a certain round, so the output would look like this:

> team_one_id, team_one_name, team_two_id, team_two_name, round_id,
>    location_name, referee

What I tried is:

```
SELECT * FROM `match` 
INNER JOIN `team` AS `team_one` ON `match`.`team_one` = `team_one`.`team_id`
INNER JOIN `team` AS `team_two` ON `match`.`team_two` = `team_two`.`team_id`
INNER JOIN `location` ON `match`.`location_id` = `location`.`location_id`
```

This kind of works but it only gives one team: the team called last (so in this case team two). I don't get why it doesn't work because I used aliasing.

How could I join these tables in the way described above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: it should work, but sometimes MySQL has a problem with columns with the same name for reasons unknown to me (I've seen this behavior before though). The easiest remedy would be to use the complete alias.column in the query:

```
SELECT 
    team_one.team_id AS team_one_id,
    team_one.team_name AS team_one_name,
    team_two.team_id AS team_two_id,
    team_two.team_name AS team_two_name,
    round_id,
    location_name,
    referee_name AS referee
FROM
    `match`
        INNER JOIN
    `team` AS `team_one` ON `match`.`team_one` = `team_one`.`team_id`
        INNER JOIN
    `team` AS `team_two` ON `match`.`team_two` = `team_two`.`team_id`
        INNER JOIN
    `location` ON `match`.`location_id` = `location`.`location_id`;
```